# concatenating 2 variables to create new variable in MS .bat-file

Tags: batch-file, variables

First time posting so please be patient.
I am trying to create a .bat file as follows

```
set a=file
set b=3
set file3=success
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo %%a%!b!%
```

I was hoping it would parse as "echo %file3%" and would then print "success". Would appreciate guidance as to how to achieve the intended result. I would also appreciate it if someone could explain what actually happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)

Comment: Quick answer: `echo !%a%%b%!`, or, to avoid delayed expansion, `call echo %%%a%%b%%%`; in both ways the inner variables become expanded prior to the outer ones...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do with delayedExpansions is to expand one variable before an other. The one which should be expanded first is the one in %percentages%, the one which should be expanded delayed is in !exclamationMarks! (which can only be used while delayedExpansion is enabled).

So in your case you have to expand a and b first -> `%a%%b%` and then the value of both -> `!file3!`

combined: `echo !%a%%b%!`

Answer (score 0):

The important thing for such, as I call them, nested variables is that the inner ones need to be replaced/expanded before the outer ones. Variables `a` and `b` are the ones I consider as the inner ones, and `file3` is the outer one.

So using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), we have two expansion phases available: the normal or immediate expansion (`%`) and the delayed expansion (`!`). Applying them in the said order the solution looks like this:

```cmd
echo !%a%%b%!
```

So at first `%a%` is expanded to `file` and `%b%` to `3`, hence the delayed expansion phase receives `!file3!`.

---

There is also a method that avoids delayed expansion: using `call`, which introduces another parsing phase where immediate expansion is repeated. The code looks like this:

```cmd
call echo %%%a%%b%%%
```

So during the first normal expansion phase `%%` becomes replaced by a literal `%`, `%a%` becomes expanded to `file`, `%b%` to `3` and the remaining `%%` becomes again replaced by `%`; so we have `%file3%` left, which is expanded by the said second parsing phase due to `call`.

---

Both of the above methods imply normal expansion for the inner variables, which can cause problems when they are changed in a parenthesised block of code, like loop, for example. To avoid normal expansion we could use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) meta-variable, which is expanded later than normal expansion but before delayed expansion:

```cmd
for %%I in ("!a!!b!") do echo !%%~I!
```

Or:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("!a!!b!") do echo !%%I!
```

Since no immediate expansion is used herein, this would also work within another `for` loop even with changing variables `a` and `b`.